# Implementing Copy Protection in a Desktop Mac App

Tags: objective-c, macos, copy-protection

I'm looking for an easy to use serial-number registration system for a small Mac App I've created. Frankly, I'm not overly concerned about pirates, but I do want a way to have a screen show up with 'Register/buy' options, and have a serial number that is related to the username/email. So, perhaps some sort of MD5 with salt? I've always heard that lots of programmers use some sort of RPN to do it, but, frankly, I have no idea how to create a serial number that would be related to registration information.

Anyways, I'd really prefer a plugin module (kinda like sparkle :) ) that would handle the registration for me, but, in lieu of that, I'd happily take some nice documentation that will lead the way to creating something like this.

Thanks much!

Comment: Why not use the Mac App Store for distribution?   It solves many of the problems you mention.

Comment: I am already... Just want to sell direct too.

Comment: That makes sense.   I'm sure there must be a 3rd party library or two available in this space... I'm just not aware of any.

Comment: The problem with a registration library is that they're predictable, making hackers to generate fake registrations very easily.  Thus why most programs have their own algorithm that generates and checks the registration key.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not concerned about predictable. If someone wants to steal it, they will.. It's mostly for esthetics TBH :)